# Install qt3 on Centos 8

Tags: centos, qt

I was able to download the qt3 yum package

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/qt3-devel-3.3.8b-51.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

but there were some dependencies missing when installing

```
 Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
 - nothing provides qt3 = 3.3.8b-51.el7 needed by qt3-devel-3.3.8b-51.el7.x86_64
 - nothing provides libmng.so.1()(64bit) needed by qt3-devel-3.3.8b-51.el7.x86_64
 - nothing provides libqt-mt.so.3()(64bit) needed by qt3-devel-3.3.8b-51.el7.x86_64
 - nothing provides libqui.so.1()(64bit) needed by qt3-devel-3.3.8b-51.el7.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

I need qt3 to compile an old software but I was not able to install it neither using the remote yum repository:

```
sudo yum install qt3 qt3-devel qt3-qtbase-devel
```

As:

```
No match for argument: qt3
No match for argument: qt3-devel
No match for argument: qt3-qtbase-devel
Error: Unable to find a match: qt3 qt3-devel qt3-qtbase-devel
```

Trying to install qt sends back to qt5 instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`sudo yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/qt3-3.3.8b-51.el7.x86_64.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/qt3-devel-3.3.8b-51.el7.x86_64.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libmng-1.0.10-14.el7.x86_64.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libmng-devel-1.0.10-14.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: @EagleOne This isn't a good idea. Installing packages from a different distribution is a good way to end up in dependency hell. You might be okay sometimes but all it takes is once to render your system unusable. When you need a version of software that isn't provided by the repos for that distribution, the best option is to build it from source.

Comment: It's not a different distribution, it's a different version of it. I've used CentOS and Fedora with packages from their older versions for almost two decades with almost no issues. And this *"once to render your system unusable"* is outright **lies**. At no point older packages could make a distro *unusable*. The most which can break is updating the entire distro to a new release or installing certain packages.

Comment: *"When you need a version of software that isn't provided by the repos for that distribution, the best option is to build it from source"* - this is **not** the best option. If an older package perfectly works, why would you waste time rebuilding it? Are you sure you can rebuild it? Have you actually built software? I've seen cases when older software cannot be rebuilt in a newer distro because GCC has become stricter and you end up having to search the Internet for patches and learn to rebuild source packages and apply patches to a spec file. Is it really worth it?

Comment: It's quite possible that qt3 from CentOS 7 will not build under CentOS 8 because they are separated by **five years** (July 2014 vs September 2019) and have very different versions of GCC, not to mention that glibc and other dependent packages have also been updated and certain libraries are not even in your distro. Trying to rebuild qt3 might lead to a can of worms which the user will have to solve ... only what for? Yeah, CentOS 7: GCC 4.8 vs CentOS 8: GCC 8.1.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Are you paying attention? It isn't lies. I have already stated that most of the time, there will be no issues but all it takes is one time. The source code is available in order to avoid things like this. I am not suggesting that it won't work. I'm am giving factual information that installing packages from repos of what is, in effect, a different operating system, is far more likely to cause issues than compiling software from source. If it works for you, then that's great but it's not best practice.

Comment: To quite myself *It's not a different distribution, it's a different version of it. I've used CentOS and Fedora with packages from their older versions for almost two decades with almost no issues.* Stop making things up. You heavily **imply** something will absolutely break as soon as you install a package from an old distro and it's a **falsehood**.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm not making things up. Stop throwing a temper tantrum because someone downvoted your answer. Deal with it. I said that installing packages from a different release which is, in effect, a different operating system isn't a good idea. I specifically stated that most of the time, you'll be okay but all it takes is one time and that makes it not worth the risk. The fact that you've done something many times with no issues is neither here nor there. Others have parsed the output of `ls` and set `777` permissions for years with no issues. That doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: @NasirRiley Mixing packages from different distros being bad is nothing but your opinion which you desperately want to make look like a fact. And you downvote anyone who happens not to share it. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Doing exactly what you have proposed has caused issues resulting in questions on this very site regarding dependency hell. This is a fact whether you like it or not. What's happening here is that you have difficulty accepting reality. There is a reason that no one other than the person asking the question has upvoted your answer or the other one. Maybe you haven't had any issues with doing it but your personal experiences don't encompass the whole world. I've had answers downvoted myself but unlike you, I'm not thin-skinned and I don't take it personally.

Comment: The fact some people had a dependency hell does not mean it will necessarily follow. Again, I've been running packages from older versions of Fedora and CentOS with zero issues for over a decade. You've spectacularly failed at argumentation once again. *I've had answers downvoted myself but unlike you, I'm not thin-skinned and I don't take it personally.* I've never downvoted people because my ego was so huge, I believed *my opinion* trumped everyone else's. Exactly what you're doing now and this looks disgusting. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: If you admitted that, *"In certain situations running packages from older distros may potentally lead to issues"* - I'd be OK with that. Instead you are **baselessly** pushing something quite different and you're downvoting people who happen to disagree because they have a ton of experience without what you believe is true. And this was supposed to be a website which prizes itself in being factual. Individuals like you prove that very very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Installing packages that belong to an older version of your distribution can be problematic and *may* make your system unusable. If you really want to use this approach:

Check if the missing packages are available from the same source
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/
and install these. The dependencies might depend on more old packages, so you might need to reiterate untill you fulfill all recursive dependencies.

The resulting program will probably depend on several old library versions, so it will probably not run on other Centos 8 systems without manually installing the library dependencies as you did on the build system. (except for the developer libraries)

---

In my opinion, **building Qt3 from source** based on the libraries of your Centos 8 system, if possible, is a better option. This will avoid the problems that can arise from using packages that are not intended for your distribution.

Statically linking your local Qt3 libraries, if possible, would allow running the program on other Centos 8 systems. Otherwise you would have to package your program with the Qt3 shared libraries.

Comment: The best option is to build it from source. It's not good practice to install packages from another distribution.

Comment: It's **not the best** option. It is **an** option.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes, it is the best option for the reason that I gave.